# fetching json from iframe -- not jsonp

Tags: javascript, html, json, iframe

How can i get json from an iframe, it is not jsonp here is what i have. (using javascript only of course)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theFrame = document.getElementById('iframe');
            var theWin = theFrame.contentWindow;
            var theDoc = theFrame.contentDocument || theFrame.contentWindow.document;
var json = theDoc;
var msgs = JSON.parse(theDoc);

for (var i = 0, l = msgs.length; i < l; i++) {
    var msg = msgs[i];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Hello ' + msg.user + ' your Id is: ' + msg.ID + 'and your message is: ' + msg.message + ' it has ' + msg.replies + ' replies';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

</script>

<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="http://jsonsource.com/not/jsonp/" width="100" height="100">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iframe is subject to the same origin policy as XHR. So if your goal is to get around that, forget it. If your goal isn't to get around that, why would you use an iframe instead of XHR (which has a much nicer API)?

That said, the only thing obviously wrong with the code is that you try to access the iframe before it exists. Move the script to after it.

Comment: Yes that is sort of my goal, but can't i get the document text of the iframe some how and use that as my json to parse?

Comment: I'll just load your bank's website into an iframe, let your browser fill in your password for you, then read it with JavaScript — **No! You can't!** — If you want to get around Same Origin, then the server providing it must provide the data as executable JavaScript (JSON-P) or you need to proxy it through the same origin as the page making the request.

Comment: @Dakota I believe you can only get the content of an iframe if it exists on the same domain as the requesting page

Comment: the JSON is stored as plain-text

Comment: @Dakota — So what? My parking space is currently storing "some air". If I want to drive somewhere I have to rent, buy or borrow a car. I can't drive "the air". Not having the data in a form + location that your JavaScript can access isn't going to change the security policy of browsers so that it can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by accessing the iframe’s contentDocument.documentElement.textContent property. (In IE, it’s innerText instead of textContent.)

Comment: Only works if the iframe is in the same domain as the requesting page.  So this won't work for what Dakota wants to do